# Qt designer and draw rectangle on screen

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt4, pyqt, qt-designer

Please see the following picture:
[image: rectangle]

In above picture, i specefied a `rectangle`, i need to `draw` same `rectangle` in my program with `Qt-Designer`, But i don't know to use what `widget`.

Can i use `qt designer` or i should just use `code`?

**Notes:** I attemp to use `QLabel` and put `---` and `|`  but they don't stick.

**My question** is , Which widget can help me?

Comment: That picture doesn't really demonstrate what you are trying to do. Can you explain some more what the problem is?

Comment: I don't have any problem, you see a rectangle in a picture that consist a set of `radio box`, i need to draw it via `Qt-Designer.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The box that you have circled in the image is a [`QGroupBox`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgroupbox.html), and can be created using the QtDesigner. Other widgets can then be inserted into like any other widget that supports layouts.

Comment: I tested `QGroubBox` today, But it doesn't have `Margin`.Do you have another solution?

Comment: You should put `checkboxes` or `radiobuttons` to `QButtonGroup` widget, but you can't create it in PyQt4 QtDesigner , so try doing that in code.